# Remove a FAB when a Fragment goes to backstack

Tags: java, android, fragment, back-stack, floating-action-button

I have seen a lot of answers but doesn't seems to find one. I am using new FAB in one of my fragments and want to remove it when that particular fragment goes to backstack, but I am not sure which method in fragment gets called when it is added to back stack and replaced by other fragment.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know the method which is called when fragment.replace() method is called or fragment is added to back stack

Answer (score 0):

Following methods were called whenever the `Fragment` is replaced or added to backstack

1) **onPause()**

2) **onStop()**

3) **onDestroyView()**

call your FAB removing method in any one of the above methods in your `Fragment`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Comment: I have tried all these method but none of them are called :(

Comment: @Ravi all three get called in my app when i replace fragments with backstack, perhaps you are replacing them wrong?

Comment: I am following google docs, but when I minimize my app then all these methods are calling but when I change fragment they are not calling !!

Comment: @Ravi These methods are called in the **fragment** that is getting replaced, not in the host activity

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion -

First, add the animation code and backstack listener in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {

    private FloatingActionButton mFab;
    private Animation mShowFab;
    private Animation mHideFab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

        mShowFab = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(this, false);
        mShowFab.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mHideFab = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
        mHideFab.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void showFab(boolean show) {
        boolean visible = mFab.isShown();
        if (show) {
            if (!visible)
                mFab.startAnimation(mShowFab);
        } else {
            if (visible)
               mFab.startAnimation(mHideFab);
       }
   }
```

And then - depending on backstack depth - show or hide the FAB:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        showFab(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);
    }
```

Comment: when onBackStackChnaged() is called?

Comment: When you push/pop a fragment to/from the back stack

Comment: onBackStackChanged() is not getting called?

Comment: Do you push the Fragment to back stack? Have you called `getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);`?

Comment: I don't want to add that particular fragment in back stack